# Storing an array of elements using Cypress

Tags: arrays, cypress

I want to store an array of strings taken from a page using cypress.

so far I have:

```
cy.get(".product-name").each(($el) => {
  let text = $el.text();

  cy.request("POST", "http://localhost:3000/sale-items", {
    text
  });
  cy.wait(1000);
});
```

As you can see I am having to make separate requests for every item. But I want to store the entire array somehow, and then make one request.

I have read [this page on variables and aliases](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/variables-and-aliases.html) but feel no closer to achieving what I want.

How to store an array of items generated from using Cypress commands?

Comment: First question, can the API body support an array as a Post body and if so have you got a schema example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `.then()` instead of `.each()` to retrieve all elements classed 'product-name'. The parameter is an iterable collection that can be converted to an array.

Ref [Array.from](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)

```js
cy.get(".product-name").then(($els) => {

  const texts = Array.from($els, el => el.innerText);

  cy.request("POST", "http://localhost:3000/sale-items", {
    texts
  });
  cy.wait(1000);
});
```

Comment: How would you achieve the same in Typescript?

Comment: @AshokkumarGanesan JavaScript is a subset of Typescript so you can use the exact same code as above

Comment: Yes I went that way!

Answer (score 3):

> cypress provide .each($elem, index, $list) method to iterate each
>   element of the array.

```
cy.get(".product-name").each(($els, index, $list) => {
   // $list itself is collection of element
   // $elem is each element of array
   // index is postion of element in array
});
```

Comment: This is a best approach too

Answer (score 0):

```
function getProductName() {
    let countProducts
    cy.get('.product-name')
        .then((elements) => {      
            countProducts = elements;
        })
    return countProducts 
}

Cypress.Commands.add('getProductName', getProductName)
```

To invoke the method from any test:

```
cy.getProductName().then(element => {
  cy.log(`Product names are: ${element.text()} `)
})
```